# How to calculate the area of a java.awt.geom.Area?

Tags: java, swing, geometry

I am looking for a way to calculate the area, in pixels, of an arbitrary instance of `java.awt.geom.Area`.

The background: I have `Shape`s in my applications that may overlap. I want to know how much one `Shape` overlaps another. The `Shape`s may be skewed, rotated, etc. If I had a function `area(Shape)` (or `Area`), I could use the intersection of two `Shape`s like so:

```
double fractionObscured(Shape bottom, Shape top) {
    Area intersection = new Area(bottom);
    intersection.intersect(new Area(top));
    return area(intersection) / area(bottom);
}
```

Comment: why double[] coords = new double[6]; and not another index is used?

Comment: You should be able to extend the polygon intersection formula to beizer curves. Then you can use path iterators to obtain near perfect areas for all shapes/areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to [`fill()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill%28java.awt.Shape%29) each scaled and [transformed](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape%28java.awt.Shape%29) [`Shape`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) with a different color using a suitable [`AlphaComposite`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html) and count the overlapping pixels in the underlying [`Raster`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html).

Addendum 1: Using this [calculator](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite) to see the effect of [`AlphaComposite.Xor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html#Xor) shows that the intersetion of any two opaque colors is zero.

Addendum 2: Counting pixels may have performance problems; sampling may help. If each  [`Shape`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) is reasonably convex, it may be possible to estimate the overlap from the ratio of the [`intersect()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#intersect%28java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D,%20java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D,%20java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D%29) area to the sum of the areas of the [`Shape`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html)s' [`getBounds2D()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html). For example,

```
Shape s1, s2 ...
Rectangle2D r1 = s1.getBounds2D();
Rectangle2D r2 = s2.getBounds2D();
Rectangle2D r3 = new Rectangle2D.Double();
Rectangle2D.intersect(r1, r2, r3);
double overlap = area(r3) / (area(r1) + area(r2));
...
private double area(Rectangle2D r) {
    return r.getWidth() * r.getHeight();
}
```

You may need to validate the results empirically.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the options of rasterizing part of the image and looking at actual sample values.

Comment: I think it's more accurate, but I also suggested a potentially faster alternative that may be sufficient.

Answer (score 12):

To find the area of a polygon using the following snippet:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n -1; i++)
{
    sum = sum + x[i]*y[i+1] - y[i]*x[i+1];
}
// (sum / 2) is your area.
System.out.println("The area is : " + (sum / 2));
```

Here n is the total number of vertices and x[i] and y[i] are the x and y coordinates of a vertex i.
Note that for this algorithm to work, the polygon must be closed. It doesent work on open polygons.

You can find mathematical alogrithms related to polygons [here](http://www.exaflop.org/docs/cgafaq/cga2.html#Subject%202.01:%20How%20do%20I%20find%20the%20area%20of%20a%20polygon?). You need to convert it to code yourself:)

Comment: Thank you for the link. This is a valid approach, but not a direction I want to go in. `Shape`s may include curve segments and may be compositions of other shapes. The math gets too hairy for me to follow.

Comment: @iter, you can use a `getPathIterator(AffineTransform at, double flatness)` to approximate the curve as a polygon.  Also the `Area` constructors will decompose the shape into non-self-intersecting components, so this algorithm will work if you adapt it to use a `PathIterator`.

Answer (score 6):

I've used this class to approximate the area of a shape in one of my projects.  It's slow but at high resolution it may still be faster than counting pixels (because the cost of counting pixels grows quadratically with resolution, but the number of line segments on the perimeter grows linearly.)

```
import static java.lang.Double.NaN;

import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.FlatteningPathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;

public abstract class Areas {
    public static double approxArea(Area area, double flatness, int limit) {
        PathIterator i =
            new FlatteningPathIterator(area.getPathIterator(identity),
                                       flatness,
                                       limit);
        return approxArea(i);
    }

    public static double approxArea(Area area, double flatness) {
        PathIterator i = area.getPathIterator(identity, flatness);
        return approxArea(i);
    }

    public static double approxArea(PathIterator i) {
        double a = 0.0;
        double[] coords = new double[6];
        double startX = NaN, startY = NaN;
        Line2D segment = new Line2D.Double(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN);
        while (! i.isDone()) {
            int segType = i.currentSegment(coords);
            double x = coords[0], y = coords[1];
            switch (segType) {
            case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                segment.setLine(segment.getX2(), segment.getY2(), startX, startY);
                a += hexArea(segment);
                startX = startY = NaN;
                segment.setLine(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN);
                break;
            case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                segment.setLine(segment.getX2(), segment.getY2(), x, y);
                a += hexArea(segment);
                break;
            case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                startX = x;
                startY = y;
                segment.setLine(NaN, NaN, x, y);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("PathIterator contains curved segments");
            }
            i.next();
        }
        if (Double.isNaN(a)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("PathIterator contains an open path");
        } else {
            return 0.5 * Math.abs(a);
        }
    }

    private static double hexArea(Line2D seg) {
        return seg.getX1() * seg.getY2() - seg.getX2() * seg.getY1();
    }

    private static final AffineTransform identity =
        AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would comment if I could. Suraj, your algorithm is correct, but the code should be

```
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < npoints ; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + Xs[i]*Ys[(i+1)%npoints] - Ys[i]*Xs[(i+1)%npoints];
        }

        return Math.abs(sum / 2);
```

In your code last vertice is not taken into account. Just a small edit :)

Answer (score 0):

The given answer is not accurate , I have found that following [solution](https://comp.lang.java.gui.narkive.com/UjvcNuPQ/calculate-the-area-of-an-java-awt-geom-area) gives much better results

```
private int calcAreaSize(Area area){
    int sum = 0;
    float xBegin=0, yBegin=0, xPrev=0, yPrev=0, coords[] = new float[6];
    for (PathIterator iterator1 = area.getPathIterator(null, 0.1); !iterator1.isDone(); iterator1.next()){
        switch (iterator1.currentSegment(coords))
        {
            case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                xBegin = coords[0]; yBegin = coords[1];
                break;
            case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                // the well-known trapez-formula
                sum += (coords[0] - xPrev) * (coords[1] + yPrev) / 2.0;
                break;
            case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                sum += (xBegin - xPrev) * (yBegin + yPrev) / 2.0;
                break;
            default:
                // curved segments cannot occur, because we have a flattened ath
                throw new InternalError();
        }
        xPrev = coords[0]; yPrev = coords[1];
    }
    return sum;
}
```