# How to find area of ruff draw or free hand drawn round or any fuzzy shape in java?

Tags: java, shapes, area

I am making an Application for a dentist in Java using Swing technology.  In my App I want to measure the area of ruff shape,free hand drawn shape,and free hand drawn circle. I also put my teeth image . In this image I have drawn one free hand shape with yellow color and I want to measure area of that circle in java. So, how can I do that? If anyone has an idea about that then please share with me.

[image]

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2263272/710951) may help. Note that if you have a `Shape` you'll need to convert it to an `Area`.

Comment: this is not work well for my question. i want to calculate any random shape? any one have math's formula for calculate any random shape?

Comment: Please, clarify. What do you mean by “random shape”? Will it be polygonal? Can it have beizer curves? From where does the shape come? Why can't you use the print - count pixels technique?

Comment: In above figure i drawn one random shape.and i want to find area of that random shape. how can i use floodfill method for finding area of this random shape?

Comment: i done it. i make logic for finding all boundary points and use flood fill method for find area.

Comment: Great! Please post an answer explaing how did you solve it and **accept** it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you save each point of the selected line-strip-array as (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and (x3,y3) .... (xN,yN) then [use this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) to get your total enclosed-area:

[image]

But be careful, this is an approximation of: "between every 2 points, there is a line"(linear interpolation). Ofcourse, calculation time is proportional to the perimeter-length.