# Find the area enclosed by a closed GeneralPath

Tags: java, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the area of a java.awt.geom.Area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263272/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-java-awt-geom-area)

I don't know how to start on this and I hope someone can help ?

I have a closed `java.awt.geom.GeneralPath` and I try to measure the square ( *area* in *squarepixel* ( `point ^ 2` ) ).

Comment: I don't really see any question there. Please be specific about what you want, and what have you tried that didn't work.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. Are you saying that you have a square described by a `GeneralPath` and that you want to find it's size? or the square of the length of the `GeneralPath` or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `GeneralPath` implements `Shape`, you can count the number times `contains()` is `true` for each pixel in the `Rectangle` returned by `getBounds()`. If need be, you can scale via the `createTransformedShape()` method of `AffineTransform`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very clever idea ! Got your point and you explained it very good. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Green's theorem and do a contour integral to calculate the area.  Integrate along the discretized path in a piecewise manner using Gauss quadrature.

This shows you how it works:

http://mathinsight.org/greens_theorem_find_area

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But this is to much for me :-) My Math Studies with integrals are too long ago.