# Plotting a hysteresis loop with jFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I need to draw hysteresis loops and then calculate the area closed within the loop. I am using jFreeChart.

consider the following data:

```
 hyst[0]=0;
       hyst[1]=0;
       hyst[2]=0.0098;
       hyst[3]=0.0196;
       hyst[4]=0.0489;
       hyst[5]=0.0879;
       hyst[6]=0.0684;
       hyst[7]=0.0489;
       hyst[8]=0.0196;
       hyst[9]=0.0098;
       hyst[10]=0;
       hyst[11]=0;
       hyst[12]=0;
       hyst[13]=0;
       hyst[14]=0;
       hyst[15]=-0.0195;
       hyst[16]=-0.0488;
       hyst[17]=-0.0391;
       hyst[18]=-0.0195;
       hyst[19]=0;
       hyst[20]=0;
```

When I try :

```
   public void plotHysteresis()
   {
       int j=0;
       int i=0;
       XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Before Treatment");
      // DefaultCategoryDataset series1 = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
       for(i=0;i<6;i++)
       {    
        series1.add(j,hyst[i]);
        logTextArea.append(Integer.toString(j) +" : " +Double.toString(hyst[i])+"\n");
        j=j+5;
       }
       j=j-5; 
       for(;i<11;i++)
       {
        j=j-5;   
        series1.add(j,hyst[i]);
        logTextArea.append(Integer.toString(j) +" : " +Double.toString(hyst[i])+"\n");
       }
        for(;i<16;i++)
       {
        j=j-5;   
        series1.add(j,hyst[i]);
        logTextArea.append(Integer.toString(j) +" : " +Double.toString(hyst[i])+"\n");
       }
           for(;i<21;i++)
       {
        j=j+5;   
        series1.add(j,hyst[i]);
        logTextArea.append(Integer.toString(j) +" : " +Double.toString(hyst[i])+"\n");
       }

    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(series1);

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart(
"Hysteresis Plot", // chart title
"Pounds (lb)", // x axis label
"Distance (inches)", // y axis label
dataset, // data
PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
true, // include legend
true, // tooltips
false // urls
);
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

    ChartPanel frame = new ChartPanel(chart);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(plotPanel.getWidth(),plotPanel.getHeight());
    plotPanel.add(frame);
    plotPanel.repaint();
   }
```

It gives me below result:

[image]

If I use :

```
 JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
"Hysteresis Plot", // chart title
"Pounds (lb)", // x axis label
"Distance (inches)", // y axis label
dataset, // data
PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
true, // include legend
true, // tooltips
false // urls
);
```

I gives:

[image]

I need a hysteresis plot that looks like:
[image]

I guess the difference is the way points are being connected. Please guide how to obtained the desired hysteresis loop with jFreeChart and then how to calculate area enclosed.

Thanks

Comment: You could plot two XYLine: one for the higher line and one for the lower one.

Comment: @assylias Is there any other solution, instead of using two lines. I need to plot many such hysteresis plots for different readings obtained for hyst[23] and need to superimpose them on the same graph and compare the enclosed area changes..

Comment: Some ideas for area are mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14175685/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change the line color as well the symbols representing the data points. I want all of them to be uniform.

It appears you've settled on `JFreeChart` for your view. Synthesizing a few other comments,

- You can make the colors and shapes of your several series homogeneous by providing a `DrawingSupplier`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14820173/230513) and shown [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115314#p174197).
- You can combine the series into a [`GeneralPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html) and estimate the area as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14175838/230513).