# Calculate area covered by GeoJSON LineString and specified weight of line

Tags: javascript, geometry, leaflet, geojson

I use the following code to draw a GPS track with Leaflet:

```
const trackJson: L.GeoJSON = L.geoJSON(trackAsJson, {
      style: {
        color: '#ff0000',
        weight: 30,
        opacity: 1
      }
    });
```

I'd like now calculate the area that is covered by this track, drawn with the specified weight/width. However, I can't find any way to achieve that. All methods that I could find require to have some form of a shape and not just only a line. So I'm either looking for a way to:

1. Turn the path and the specified weight into a shape
   or
2. Find a direct method to calculate the area of a path and a weight.

Comment: I think you want to [buffer the polyline](https://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer) and calculate the [area](https://turfjs.org/docs/#area) of the resulting polygon, instead.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thanks. That sounds good!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need an approximation, you could render the track / path and count the pixels.

[How to calculate the area of a java.awt.geom.Area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263272/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-a-java-awt-geom-area)